# Qual è il significato di "barracani" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Uscii dalla libreria, mi fermai in piazza Cavour. La giornata era bella, via Foria sembrava innaturalmente pulita e solida malgrado i **barracani** che puntellavano la Galleria.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "barracano" in alcuni dizionari e ho visto che può trattarsi di un tipo di veste o di tessuto, ma questo non sembra avere senso nel contesto del passaggio precedente. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "barracani" in questo brano?

Comment: Secondo me l'autrice ha preso un (altro) granchio e si è confusa con *barbacane*. O forse è un refuso. http://treccani.it/vocabolario/barbacane

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il termine “barracani” non ha alcun senso in quel contesto. È certamente un refuso (dell'autrice o del tipografo) per *barbacani*

Vedi http://treccani.it/vocabolario/barbacane